# Eclipse and Processing PApplet Error

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

Currently I am trying to make a maze game. I am simply trying to load in the sprites and get the program going but it is not working correctly and giving me an error message stating: 
Usage: PApplet [options]  [sketch args]
See the Javadoc for PApplet for an explanation.
I have read up some answers that have some sort of solution, however I have no idea what they are talking about since I am a 13 year old beginner/intermediate programmer. Here is my code that is giving me the error message:

```
package MegaPackage;
import java.util.*;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;
//Main method. Insert public variables and entities here.
public class FlatShooter extends PApplet {
PImage background;
PImage squareImage;
PImage life1Image;
PImage life2Image;
PImage life3Image;
PImage redEnemyImage;
public float xSpeedPlayer = 9;
public int score;
public int enemies;
public int lives;
public boolean moving = false;
public boolean moving2 = false;
public Square square;
public void setup(){
    size(900, 900);
    background=loadImage("background.jpeg");
    squareImage=loadImage("player.png");
    life1Image=loadImage("life.png");
    life2Image=loadImage("life.png");
    life3Image=loadImage("life.png");
    square = new Square(squareImage, (width-100)/2, height * 4/5);
}
//Movement for player and other items
public void keyPressed(){
    if( key == 'd' || key == 'D'){
        moving = true;
    }
    if(key == 'a' || key == 'A'){
        moving2 = true;
    }
}
//Stopping movement for players and other items
public void keyReleased(){
    if( key == 'd' || key == 'D'){
        moving = false;
    }
    if(key == 'a' || key == 'A'){
        moving2 = false;
    }
}
public class Square{
    PImage square;
    float xPos;
    float yPos;     
    public Square(PImage squareImage, float startX, float startY){
        square=squareImage;
        xPos=startX;
        yPos=startY;
    }
public void drawSquare(){
    image(square, xPos, yPos);
}
}
public void move(float x, float y){
    if(moving){
        x += xSpeedPlayer;
    }
    if (moving2){
        x-= xSpeedPlayer;
        }
    }
}
```

If you can give this answer in fairly simple terms and an easy solution please do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're working from an outdated tutorial? As of Processing 3, the `PApplet` class no longer extends the `Applet` class, so you can't run it as an applet.

Instead, you have to add a `main()` method that then calls `PApplet.runSketch()`.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on using Processing as a Java library available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java).

But if you're just starting out, you really might want to spend some time in the Processing editor before jumping to more advanced programming using Eclipse.

Comment: Does the code on your website still work? I always get `C:\Users\Norman\IdeaProjects\ProcessingGame\src\MySketch.java:3:8
java: cannot access android.app.Activity` and I'm using the exact same code as the (first) one on your website.